# Missing arguement

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I initialised  `weatherreport.Weather to self.weather` in the main file which is responsible for my basic main window.

See the image [![here][1]][1]

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        
        #Initialize Weather module
        self.weather = weatherreport.Weather()

    def show_weather(self):
        city_name = tk.Entry(self.root, text = "Enter city name : ", width = 15)
        self.weather(city_name)
```

````
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
        self.city = city```

U can clearly come to know what error I'm facing. I searched all over internet or atleast what i can. None explains this. I'd love to rectify this but i need some help here. It is a small side project for my internals.

Thanking you in anticipation


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLRqQ.png
````

Comment: Paste error and code as text, not as an image.

Comment: The error is when you instantiate your class, not in the definition of its methods.

Comment: You are not showing the right line of error.
in the img - your showing line 59 of init but the error states there's an issue with line 32
my guess youv'e got 2 init and you only changed one of them

Comment: I rectified my mistake in the question and i found how to resolve the error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to paste *code* instead of *images of code* so it is easier to help you.

Your error is a simple and self-explanatory one. The error is: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'city'`. Let's break it down.

`__init__()` is a special function of classes in Python, sometimes called the "constructor". This function gets called when you create an "instance" or "object" of that class.

For example, if I have the following dummy class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print("bar")
```

When I create an instance of Foo by doing something like `x = Foo()`, then `__init__()` gets called and I should see "bar" get printed before the assignment happens.

The error is telling us that this special function of the Weather class is expecting an argument, but never got it. If you look at the `__init__` function for the Weather class, you will see that it takes in a parameter called "city".

So to fix this, you have to give provide the arguments to `__init__` when creating your class. Something like

```
self.weather = weatherreport.Weather("Detroit")
```

Comment: Hey thanks for clearing my doubt. Now i understand that since im using the contructor and not the get_report() method directly. So, i need to call it inside the class Weather.

Comment: Ok u expalined me well. but i assigned weatherreport.Weather to self.weather which means I'm passing the city name to Weather class only right. Which is indirectly weatherreport.Weather(city_name). So why  do i get error.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see the error properly, you should post the error and the code as text and not as an picture.

But your `__init__` calls two arguments. `self` and `city`.

So you should inicialize it with those two arguments. From the error it seems like you only have 1 argument in the function.

Comment: I.m new to stackoverflow since i hv my frnds and teachers to help me, but in this lockdown it is not that. So I'll rectify it. By the way thanks i understood. I passed the argument to a function in the class which is wrong. I need to pass it to the constructor since im using the self keyword. Thanks.